# Windows IPv6 raw sockets - why don't I see incoming packets?

Tags: c++, windows, ipv6, raw-sockets

I'm writing a C++ program on Windows that creates a raw socket, binds it to an IPv6 interface and tries to recv IPv6 packets. For some reason `recv()` doesn't return any packet although I'm sure that IPv6 packets **are** received on the interface (I verified using Wireshark). 
What could be the problem?

Here is the code I've written:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <string>
#include "IpUtils.h"

#define SIO_RCVALL  0x98000001
#define RAW_SOCKET_BUFFER_LEN 65536

int main()
{
    int timeout = 10; // 10 seconds
    std::string ipv6Addr = "my IPv6 address...";
    int numOfPackets = 1; // try to read just one packet

    WSADATA wsaData;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

    SOCKET fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IPV6);
    if (fd < 0)
    {
        printf("error in socket creation\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf("socket creation succeeded\n");

    struct sockaddr_in6 localAddrIPv6;
    localAddrIPv6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    inet_pton(AF_INET6, ipv6Addr.c_str(), &localAddrIPv6.sin6_addr.s6_addr);
    localAddrIPv6.sin6_port = 0; // Any local port will do
    localAddrIPv6.sin6_scope_id = 0;

    if (bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&localAddrIPv6, sizeof(localAddrIPv6)) < 0)
    {
        printf("error in bind, error code was %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(fd);
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf("bind succeeded\n");

    int n = 1;
    DWORD dwBytesRet;
    if (WSAIoctl(fd, SIO_RCVALL, &n, sizeof(n), NULL, 0, &dwBytesRet, NULL, NULL) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Call to WSAIotcl(%ul) failed with error code %d\n", SIO_RCVALL, WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(fd);
        return 1;
    }
    else
        printf("call to WSAIotcl succeeded\n");

    DWORD timeoutVal = timeout * 1000;
    setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (const char*)&timeoutVal, sizeof(timeoutVal));

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfPackets; i++)
    {
        char* buffer = new char[RAW_SOCKET_BUFFER_LEN];
        memset(buffer, 0, RAW_SOCKET_BUFFER_LEN);

        printf("start recv for packet #%d\n", i);
        int bufferLen = recv(fd, buffer, RAW_SOCKET_BUFFER_LEN, 0);
        if (bufferLen < 0)
        {
            printf("recv failed with an error code %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(fd);
            delete [] buffer;
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Got a packet with len %d\n", bufferLen);
        }

        delete [] buffer;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`IpUtils.h` contains a Windows implementation for `inet_pton()` as described [here][1].

The compilers I'm using are MinGW / MinGW-w64.

Also, here is the makefile I'm using:

```
# All Target
all:
    g++.exe -c -o IpUtils.o IpUtils.cpp
    g++.exe -c -o main.o main.cpp
    g++.exe -o test.exe main.o IpUtils.o -lws2_32

# Clean Target
clean:
    del main.o
    del IpUtils.o
    del test.exe
```

The output I'm getting after running the program is:

```
socket creation succeeded
bind succeeded
call to WSAIotcl succeeded
start recv for packet #0
recv failed with an error code 10060 <== WSAETIMEDOUT which means timeout expired
```

***EDIT:***

Following the comments below, I managed to see IPv6 traffic by replacing the line `SOCKET fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IPV6)` with`SOCKET fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP)`. However the packets I'm getting don't have the IPv6 header which is an expected behavior (see [Remy Lebeau's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52218511/windows-ipv6-raw-sockets-why-dont-i-see-incoming-packets#comment91401511_52218511)). So my question now is how do I know the protocol of the payload I'm getting? Usually the payload protocol is mentioned in the IPv6 header, but since I don't have it, how can I know/guess it?

Comment: At least the `IPPROTO_IPV6` in `socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IPV6);`  means that you will only receive IPv6 packets that itself carry an IPv6 packet (i.e. that parameter is a filter for the protocol field within the IPv6 packet). So try to receive IPv6 packets carrying UDP or TCP or perhaps ICMPv6 instead. I don't see any means in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2#creating-a-raw-socket) to say you want to receive any kind of IPv6 packet..

Comment: Thanks! what protocol should I use if I want to receive any IPv6 packet (UDP, TCP, ICMPv6, etc.)?

Comment: As mentioned I don't see any way in the docs to do that. If you're building some sort of sniffer, look at using the winpcap library instead.

Comment: When I replace `IPPROTO_IPV6` with `IPPROTO_IP` do see traffic coming to the socket but unfortunately it doesn't include the IPv6 header. I tried setting the `IP_HDRINCL` socket option: `int on = 1; setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, &on, sizeof(on));` and also setting `IPV6_HDRINCL`: `int on = 1; setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IPV6, IPV6_HDRINCL, &on, sizeof(on));` but none of them help. Any ideas?

Comment: @fx23 `IP_HDRINCL` and `IPV6_HDRINCL` are for outgoing packets you send, not for incoming packets you read. [Read the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winsock/tcp-ip-raw-sockets-2), in particular: "*For IPv4..., an application receives the IP header at the front of each received datagram regardless of the `IP_HDRINCL` socket option. For IPv6..., an application receives everything after the last IPv6 header in each received datagram regardless of the` IPV6_HDRINC` socket option. **The application does not receive any IPv6 headers using a raw socket**.*

Comment: Thanks for the info, this is very useful. So if IPv6 header is not included, how do I know the packet payload protocol (i.e UDP, TCP, ICMPv6, etc.)?